# How can i render an OBJ file with texture using mitsuba renderer?

Tags: graphics, render

I'm trying to render a simple obj file with texture using mitsuba2 renderer. Following is my xml config. The object shape looks correct but texture isn't getting loaded (Getting a black object on a white background).

```
<scene version='2.0.0'>

<path value="mitsuba2/resources/data/common"/>

<integrator type="aov">
    <string name="aovs" value="sh_normal:sh_normal"/>
    <integrator type="direct" name="my_image"/>
</integrator>

<emitter type="constant" id="my_envmap">
    <float name="radiance" value="0.5" />
</emitter>

<shape type="obj">
    <string name="filename" value="115_norm.obj"/>
    <bsdf type="plastic">
        <texture name="diffuse_reflectance" type="bitmap">
            <string name="filename" value="115.png"/>
        </texture>
    </bsdf>
</shape>

<sensor type="perspective">
    <transform name="to_world">
        <lookat origin="0, -2.5, 2.5"
                target="0, 0, 0"/>
    </transform>

    <float name="fov" value="30"/>


    <sampler type="independent">
        <integer name="sample_count" value="2048"/>
    </sampler>
</sensor>
</scene>
```

Can someone help with this? My objective is just to render a obj file with texture and below camera location settings.

Comment: Try it maybe without texture to see if you have other problems : 

<bsdf type="plastic">
        <rgb name="diffuse_reflectance" value="0.940, 0.271, 0.361" />
        <float name="int_ior" value="1.9" />
</bsdf>

Comment: The way how you specified the texture is correct. It works for me with my files. Probably something else is wrong with your script